# console.log prints only one line in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to print something like:

```
#
##
###
####
#####
######
#######
```

My code is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Learning Javascript</title>
</head>
<body>


<script type="text/javascript">
    for (var i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
        for ( var j = 1 ; j <= i ; j++ )
        {
            console.log("#");
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It gives only a single #:

```
#
```

Why am I not getting expected output in console log? 
I have tried both chrome and firebug.

Comment: it'll give a single # 28 times, is that right

Comment: Yes.... I am getting something like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, I believe you're getting 28 of them, but the console "merges" them into one.

[image]

In any event, your code is printing `#` on a separate line each time. You want to concatenate `j` `#`s and print that in the outer for loop.

Alternatively, you can do this:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
    console.log("#".repeat(i));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In console same value will be counted instead of printing separately

If you wanna to to print separately then concat as string then print

Try like this

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
    var str="";
    for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
       str+="#"
    }
    console.log(str);
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/76fbjw9h/)**

Comment: I am assuming ur missing a ";" after `str+="#"`.. shouldn't it be `str+="#";`.. not that it matters, even without it; still works perfect..

Comment: Thanks for pointing . it's just a typo . it's not a big deal in javascript though @GMB